# Cakephp url: hide controller name on main page

Tags: php, cakephp

When i open website with localhost/site_name, url immediately becomes localhost/site_name/default_controller_name.

How can i hide it, so that the url only on that main front page becomes localhost/site_name ?

**EDIT** this is default controller for front page

```
public function index() {


    $this->set('list', $this->User->Mobilenetwork->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array('id', 'network')
        )));


    if($this->Auth->user() ) 
    { 
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'index'));
    }


   if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
      //saving data. this is a mess currently, i need to move majority of this code to the model
    }
```

Comment: What is your default controller now? Is it Pages? And did you add that action to Auth allowed actions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you adjusted your "routes.php" file to make the root url direct to "localhost/site_name/default_controller_name"?  If not, go to the routes file within your Config folder and change:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

(which is the default) to this:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'default_controller_name', 'action' => 'index'));
```

*not sure what version of CakePHP you're running; the above is for 2.4 (though it may be applicable for earlier versions as well).

Comment: hm i tried that one ( Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index')); ) but the outcome is: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: in my users controller i have: if($this->Auth->user() ) { redirect.. } and  if ($this->request->is('post')) { ... }

Comment: Do you mean that when you go to "root/mysite" in automatically changes the url to "root/mysite/users"?  Also, what version of CakePHP are you on?

Comment: which code should i post? I'm running latest Cakephp version

Comment: @jackel414 yes, www.site.com  becomes www.site.com/users

Comment: can you post the controller function that you are trying to access with "localhost/mysite"?

Comment: Based on your edit, I would guess if the request is not "Post" and the user is not Auth, then you get what you want.  Otherwise (assuming you enter the first loop), you get "localhost/mysite/contacts".  If that last page is what most users will hit when they first access your site (due to the redirect), I would try changing your routes files to make "localhost/mysite/contacts" your root url.  you can manually send users to the above front page first, and when they finally land on "localhost/mysite/contacts", it should appear as "localhost/mysite", since it's your root url

Comment: hm ok ty i will see, let me get back to this problem later, when i finish some important things :)